# Accumulator for JSON Array

Tags: java, android, json

I have a json object that holding a json array of json objects(i know confusing but) in the objects are keys (name, value) i want to add up all of the values for a given key but im not clear on how to do it  the [javadoc's](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html) doesn't help much. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Peel the onion, a layer at a time.  JSON is blazingly simple, with only two main types of objects.  It's just that they can be combined in an infinite number of ways.  But at any one time you're only dealing with either an "array" or an "object" (map).

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand the JSONArray is a value that matches a key in the JSONObject.

You need to extract the JSONArray with the `get` method of the JSONObject, and then iterate it using the `get` method of the JSONArray.

Example:

```
int ans = 0;
JSONObject jObj;
jArr = (JSONArray) jObj.get("arr");
for(int i=0; i<jArr.length(); i++)
{
    JSONObject o = (JSONObject) jArr.get(i);
    ans += (int) o.get(theGivenKey);
}
```

Of course you need to handle nulls everywhere. Good luck. :-)